# Synchronous countdown across users on Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am developing a multiplayer game (for scientific experiment) where participants engage in 20 rounds of interactive decision making. Each round has 3 stages, each should last maximum for 30 seconds. I wonder what would be a good way to implement the countdown.

Currently, I am using a client side approach. On the creation of the round template, I use client side timer that submits the answer of the participant when it reaches 0. This is working fine so far (because everyone starts the game at the exact same time, and the next round starts only after everyone has submitted an answer). I am not sure that this is a good way to do it, considering that participants might disconnect (go offline, close the browser, have connectivity issues) and might manipulate the sessions or something.

Would it be a better approach to do a server side timer? For instance, a collection that contains the timer, and participants subscribe to that collection? If so, how would one implement a server-side countdown? Also, would this approach cause high demand on the server, given that every second in the countdown (that we display in the template) would require listening to data on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never trust the client.

With that in mind, we need to find a way for the client to display the remaining time, according to the time the server chose... First, the server puts the end-time of a round when it is created (or start time + duration).

Now that everyone has the same end-time which is according to the server, we need to sync them with server time. Let's use [mizzao:timesync](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-timesync) it's pretty straightforward, it receives the server time, and creates a difference from the client time. Monitors the client time to make sure no weird clock changes occur and even considers the latency. This might be a bit more than what you need, but it's already done, so less work for us!

Now that we know the current server time, and the round end time, we can easily show how long we got remaining! If a player comes back after a disconnect or refresh, both of those times will still be valid and they'll be able to continue the game.

Comment: Great! this is what I am looking for .. I am a bit newbie here so if you can add some snippets of code to implement this, you'd help me greatly!

Comment: You try first, all I'd write would be outside of your context... If you happen to have problems or get errors when trying, come back to SO to get help with specific code.